# Step by step weather API tutorial

Tags: weather-api

Where can I find a good step by step tutorial about some api weather implementation? I´m really new in this, so official documentation is not always as clear as I need to begin to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use various xml from various sites to access weather data.
[This site](http://maniacdev.com/2010/10/tutorial-using-core-location-and-google-xml-weather-api/) Will surely help you.