# Open source weather api for profit iOs app?

Tags: iphone, ios4, weather-api

Have to use a weather api for a profit org app.

Is there any api avail for free?

Comment: Free != open source, nor vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're looking for something like this:

http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/

And here is another question that somebody asked:

[Step by step weather API tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196752/step-by-step-weather-api-tutorial)

Looks like there is a Google API for that, too.